# How to use identity server 4 with windows service based on Dot net framework?

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

I need to run a window service based on the dot net framework. I can't upgrade to .net core due to some reasons. I have identity server 4 running with Open Id Connect and I need to extract data from one API from the window service.

What is the best way to do this?
Should I get an access token from the identity server using HTTP Client and then call API with bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

Using the client credentials flow you can have the service login using its clientid/password and retrieve an access token.

You can do do that using a simple HttpClient call or using the helper methods in the [IdentiytModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html) library.

When the access token expires, you just login again and get a new token.